# Copy and Paste range as values with python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, automation, xlwings

I started using Python with xlwings for Excel automation tasks. Currently, I am struggling to do copy/paste functions in cases I need to paste data as values. (excluded from inside formulas)

Lets say Excel Cell A1 contains "=A2+C2" which returns "72"
How do I format the cell with xlwings so that the cell contains only the number?

Could someone please provide me with some code solutions?

There must be something like this in xlwings but I did not find anything in their documentation.

Just to clarify: Normal copy/paste with formulas works fine for me.

Thank you very much for anything helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Received solution on GitHub post: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1337

Closing this as resolved now.